# Copy words to clipboard from double click

Tags: java, awt, clipboard, awtrobot

I am trying to copy words from anywhere (like MS word, pdf, not from any java component) to clip board when I double click on it. Therefore, I use `awt.Robot` to copy that selected word to clip board after double click on it. After copy, the word will return. Therefore, I use two method `copy_From_Original` and `copy_From_ClipBoard`.

The problem is when I copy word, it will show the previous word that clipboard content not the current copied one.

> If there are, another ways to do this process feel free to say it.

Thanks. Sorry for my bad English.

```
public class copyWord {

public static String copy_From_Original() {
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(copyWord.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    String word = copy_From_ClipBoard();
    return word;
}

private static String copy_From_ClipBoard() {

    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
    try {
        String result = (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
        return null;
    }
} }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Robot for this.  You haven’t said what type of component contains the double-clicked text, but if it’s a JTextField or JTextArea or any other subclass of JTextComponent, you can simply call [copy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#copy--).

If it’s an AWT TextField or TextArea, you can use place the selection on the clipboard yourself:

```
String text = textField.getSelectedText();

Clipboard clipboard = textField.getToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents(new StringSelection(text), null);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer vgr. The selected text is not belongs to any component. It is from another location. Like MS word or something. So that’s why I use robot.

Comment: That presents a challenge.  Java can’t really monitor or control activity in other applications.

Comment: That is bad. I do not need to select a word just need to copy a selected word.  To do that no need to control or monitor another application. Just send windows normal copy signal and grab it to clipboard. Just all. The robot will do that.

Comment: The Clipboard won’t change right away just because your Robot performs a Ctrl-C.  At the very least, you should use [EventQueue.invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-) to wrap any subsequent reading of the clipboard contents.  You may also need a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to delay the read, but unfortunately, any delay would be heuristic and arbitrary, and therefore not completely reliable.

Comment: Yes you are right thanks for helping. I use Thread.sleep(500); now it works.